# How to get a list of specific fields values from objects stored in a list?

Tags: java, collections

Say I have an list of objects with two fields `field1` and `field2`, both of String type.

How do I get a list of all `field1` values without having to iterate over the list, if it is at all possible?

Comment: No, there isn't, in common case. Or do you have more details?

Comment: "without having to iterate through", Not at all, I guess.

Comment: `without having to iterate through the list` you mean you wouldn't iterate through the list, or even a library wouldn't? Basically do you just want something easy to type, or really O(1) access to a sub-sets of objects based on conditions? It's 2 entirely different questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object is a reference towards a memory address. Then, the fields of this objects are other references towards other memory addresses. 
Hence, a list of objects is a list of references. So, it's impossible for the list to direclty access the object fields (references given by the references). The short answer is no.

Note: anyway you'll find an API that does what you want, it still loops in the inside.

Comment: Note necessarily. You could implement a collection that would, on insertion, add elements to a list, which you index based on searching critera, and then return a the list itself directly. This way, insertion would be somewhat inefficient, but retrieval would allow to do what the OP wants.

Comment: That's true, but such a collection would be very specific to the type of objects it contains, instead of being generic.

Comment: partly, yes, as to not make completely "fixed" you'd need to use bounding interfaces, or reflection, so you either need to impose a slight rigidity to the types you can insert, or a performance and complexity impact to the indexer. But that's perfectly doable, though. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if some of the libraries and language extensions that have implemented to provide querying capabilities to java collections and composite objects were using something along the lines of the second approach.

Comment: I don't agree here; it's true that logically a list must be the list of references, but a list is just an interface -- if it returns the right thing, it need not have a backing store.  See my answer below for a version that does not loop and satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 106):

Fortunately, you can do this using **[Java 8 - Streams](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm)**

Assume you have an entity named **YourEntity**

```
public class YourEntity {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public YourEntity(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
}
```

Declare you list of **YourEntity** using:

```
List<YourEntity> entities = Arrays.asList(new YourEntity("text1", "text2"), new YourEntity("text3", "text4"));
```

You can extract the list of **field1** in one shot in this way:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<String> field1List = entities.stream().map(YourEntity::getField1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or in this way

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<String> field1List = entities.stream().map(urEntity -> urEntity.getField1()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can print all the items also using java 8 :)

```
field1List.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
text1
text3
```

Comment: how can this be achieved for any number of fields in a entity class ? Say, I am writing one common method to achieve this on any number of fields in a single entity class or any entity class I send as an argument in the method.

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
List<Entity> entities = getEntities();
List<Integer> listIntegerEntities = Lambda.extract(entities, Lambda.on(Entity.class).getFielf1());
```

the LambdaJ allows to access collections without explicit loops, so instead of have more lines of code to iterate the list yourself, you let LambdaJ do it.

Comment: This answer should definitely be updated with a short description of what's used here (LambdaJ?)

Answer (score 5):

### Depends...

... whether your questions refers to `avoiding iterating over the collection` either:

- *in terms of ease of implementation at call points*
- **or** *in terms of the algorithmic complexity*.

Concretely, do you mean:

- *you don't want to type in an iterating construct yourself* (simply use a convenience library),
- *or you actually want something that would return elements auto-magically in O(1) without needing to process them* (and have perfect access)?

See below for solutions and options.

---

### Using Convenience Libraries

If it's the first one, then look at Google Guava, LambdaJ, FunctionalJava or other libraries that implement basic functional constructs and will allow you to do what you want in a few expressive calls. But keep in mind these do what is says on the tin: they will filter, collect or transform a collection, and will iterate through its elements to do this.

For instance:

- [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

  ```
  Set<String> strings = buildSetStrings();  
  Collection<String> filteredStrings =
      Collections2.filter(strings, Predicates.containsPattern("^J"));
  ```
- [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/):

  ```
  Array<Integer> a = array(97, 44, 67, 3, 22, 90, 1, 77, 98, 1078, 6, 64, 6, 79, 42);
  Array<Integer> b = a.filter(even);
  ```
- [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/):

  ```
  List<Integer> biggerThan3 = filter(greaterThan(3), asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
  ```

---

## Perfect Access

If it's the second one, **this is not possible as-is**, **except** if you architectured everything from the start so that **your objects should be managed by a custom collection class that would indexing your objects based on their field values on insertion**.

It would keep them in buckets indexed by said value to be readily available for you to retrieve them as a list or set on demand.

As mentioned in the comments below dounyy's answer, designing such a custom collection would probably have an impact on the API of the elements it would accept (most likely by defining a super interface to use for element types), or would require a fairly intricate implementation to resolve members dynamically (most likely by using reflection), if you ever wanted this collection to be generic.

Comment: Perfect access is also possible just by implementing the `List<String>` interface to defer to the underlying `List<Entity>` interface.  That introduces no unnecessary iteration; accessing the `ith` element of the `List<String>` is exactly as expensive as accessing the `ith` element of the `List<Entity>`.  No API impact, either.

Comment: @user295691: Yes. Different approach, but same answer though: OP can't do it without writing a custom implementation.

Comment: Custom implementation, yes, but not "architect[ing] everything from the start" -- this can be quickly used if you want to, say, call `Collections.frequency()` or `Collections.binarySearch()` on the field inside the object.

Answer (score 4):

Neither java as a language nor JDK libraries do not do what you want yet. You can either use [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) or wait for Java 8 that is expected to include lambda expressions.

Comment: How would that avoid the iteration? Lambda J would still do it for you. otherwise you could already use Google Guava for that, or LambdaJ, or FunctionalJava, or lots of other ones. But they all iterate through the structures, of course.

Comment: You are right, @haylem. Obviously somebody must iterate over the collection. No way to avoid it. When closures will be introduced into java they will do the same behind the scene. The tools you mentioned just help us to write shorter code.

Answer (score 3):

Let the object be of the following class.

```
public class Bike {

    String bikeModel;
    Int price;
}
```

And now there is list of bikes called bikeList of type List

So now we want a list of bikemodels of all the bikes in the above list.

```
bikeList.map{ Bike b -> b.bikeModel }.toCollection(arrayListOf())
```

returns an array list of first field of all the bike objects in the bikeList

Answer (score 2):

Ancient question, but I came upon it while looking to see if I could improve on a similar solution.

You can implement the `List<String>` interface without creating a fleshed-out `ArrayList<String>`, and thus not iterating over the parent object.

```
final List<Entity> entities = getEntities()
final List<String> field1 = new AbstractList() {
    public String get(int index) {
        return entities.get(index).getField1();
    }
    public int size() {
        return entities.size();
    }
}
```

That gives you a List without iterating over the parent object.

Random access to the derived `List<String>` will be as expensive as random access to the underlying `List<Entity>`; if you're using an implementation of `List<Entity>` that does not provide quick random access, you might have to jump through a couple of hoops (i.e. implementing more methods of `List<String>`.  But this should work for 99% of the cases where you need a light-weight adapter.

Comment: That'd work if the underlying list implementation allows random access indeed (e.g. ArrayList). Note that the OP's question was not about accessing just one value though.

Comment: @haylem If the original list does not support random access (e.g. `LinkedList<Entity>`), then you would extend `AbstractSequentialList<String>` instead -- this is noted in my answer (indirectly, but I think clearly).  The core concept here is that you can create the requested list in `O(1)` time and use `O(1)` space.  Can you clarify what you mean by "accessing just one value"?  You can access all values in the derived list; it will be no more expensive than calling `get()` on the underlying list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! Its possible.
But you have to do some crooked work.

1. Create a inner class with required variables.
   Eg: here am going to use 2 variables.( TNAME and TABTYPE).

   ```
    public class storeTables {
           private String tablename = "";
           private String tabletype = "";
           public storeTables(String a, String b)
           {
               this.setTablename(a);
               this.setTabletype(b);
           }
           public void setTablename(String tablename) {
               this.tablename = tablename;
           }
           public String getTablename() {
               return tablename;
           }
           public void setTabletype(String tabletype) {
               this.tabletype = tabletype;
           }
           public String getTabletype() {
               return tabletype;
           }}
   ```
2. Create a List of the inner class created above and dont forget to encapsulate it.

   ```
   private List<storeTables> objlist= new ArrayList<storeTables>();
   ```
3. Get the value stored to the list as a inner class object.

   ```
   String Query="SELECT * FROM TAB";
   while(rs.next())
   {
   String tname=rs.getString("TNAME");
   String tabtype=rs.getString("TABTYPE");
   getObjlist().add(new storeTables(tname,tabtype));
           }
   ```
4. create a DATAMODEL and push the list to the datamodel

   ```
   private DataModel selectableItems= new ListDataModel(objlist);
   ```
5. get the warpped data to another list.

   ```
   List<storeTables> items= (List<storeTables>)selectableItems.getWrappedData();
   ```
6. Finally!!! printing the data.

   ```
   for(storeTables item:items){
   System.out.println(item.getTablename());
       }
   ```

TADA !!!! it will print only the tablename and not the tabtype ;)
Believe that there is nothing impossible in java
Any doubts!!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You have to traverse the whole list and get each "field1" value from each object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create an hashmap in this way:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> map;
```

The key would be the field.
Doing this way, when you ask the HashMap to retrieve you the object corresponding to the field that you want, the map would return you an ArrayList cointaing all of the elements which has that field.

Answer (score 0):

Without Iterating this is not possible .You can reduce iteration somehow but it is must.

Answer (score 0):

Add the values of records in different lists and by using the one or two iterator simply print
the seperate values.like follows:

```
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from stu");
List data=new ArrayList();
List data1=new ArrayList();
while(rs.next())
{
   data.add(rs.getString(1));
   data1.add(rs.getString(2));
}
Iterator it=data.iterator();
Iterator it1=data1.iterator();
while(it1.hasNext())
{
   System.out.println(" "+it.next()+"  "+it1.next());
}
```

Comment: why does your solution have an SQL in it??