# How to extract the n-th elements from a list of tuples in Java?

Tags: java

Basically I try to extract only the 2nd element from the list of tuples. 
Scala has a  very nice solution to this (which somewhat looks like 
this x._2) but I don't know how I can do this in Java.

```
public static ArrayList<House> house = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new House(321321, 2.5),
                                                                     new House(456544, 3.0),
                                                                     new House(789687, 4.0));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get specific ArrayList item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920602/get-specific-arraylist-item)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997139/how-to-get-a-list-of-specific-fields-values-from-objects-stored-in-a-list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `House` class has getters for these values e.g.:

```
public class House {
    private final int value1;
    private final double value2;

    public House(final int value1, final double value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public int getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public double getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

You can do a map and collect to get the second value:

```
final List<Double> value2s = house.stream().map(House::getValue2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```